# How to trigger swap space usage on linux?

Tags: swap

Is there a linux command or process I can run to trigger or force it to use swap at a high rate, e.g. exhausting 50% of swap space? I tried copying files but only see memory usage going up and down.

Comment: https://linuxhint.com/understanding_vm_swappiness/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sysctl -w vm.swappiness=100
```

then copy files to `/dev/shm`